# Alignment of image an <p> tag

Tags: html, css

I have an image of a map, and I want to add the address to the right hand side of it, I can't seem how to figure it out. Can any one help, this is the part of the coding I'm using:

```
<div id="main">
<span style="margin-top:5px;
        margin-left:5px;
              text-align:right;">
       <h1 align="center" style="font-size:40px;"><span style="color:red;">Contact</span><span style="color:#FFFFFF;"> Us</span></h1>

  <img id="map" src="images/map.png" title="Image of Map for Krazie Needles." align="centre" />
<p align="left" style="margin-left:5px;
          margin-top: 5px;">
    45 Station Road
```

with the css code

```
       #main
{

    margin-top:42px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    background:rgba(16,16,17,0.70);
    height:85%;
    width:90%;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2.5px #888888;
    border-radius:5px;
}   

img#map
{
    margin-left:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

I want to align the < p > tag next to the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to maintain your styling but have removed all inline styles.

```css
#main
{
    margin: 42px auto;
    position:relative;
    background:rgba(16,16,17,0.70);
    width:90%;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2.5px #888888;
    border-radius:5px;
}   

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}

.map
{
    display:inline;
    margin: 0 5px 0;
    border-radius:5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:#fff;
}

.address {
    display:inline;
    vertical-align: top;
}​
```

```html
<div id="main">
<h1><span class=red>Contact</span> Us</h1>
<img class=map src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" title="Image of Map for Krazie Needles." />
<p class=address>45 Station Road</p>
</div>​
```

Comment: Thanks Aniket! Much appreciated :) Worked and displayed as I wanted it to. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @JakeNemoBrogan Not a problem :) We are here to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float: left;` on the image tag (see [float at W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats)), or place the image inside the `<p>`.

Answer (score 1):

In the img tag, change the (incorrect) `align="centre"` to `align="left"`.

(Note, there is no center attribute on img tag.)

Comment: Yes. To clarify: it's never "centre", always "center". But `img` doesn't support that, so you'd have to put it in a container that does support it if you do want to center the img (which you don't). Also, the align attribute is deprecated and you should replace it with a style.

Comment: Ahh yes, I see. I'm still very much new at HTML, didn't know "center" wasn't supported by the img tag. As for the wrong spelling, I'm English, and find it a bit hard getting used to using the American spelling. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add **float:left** to image css. If you want to put the address on Map you have to add **position:absolute** to paragraph with address css.